# We can not retrieve image url for the product from 3dcart.com

Tags: rest

we are using the following Rest API with default values for limit and offset.
https://apirest.3dcart.com/Help/Api/GET-3dCartWebAPI-v1-Products-catalogid-Images_limit_offset

We are invoking on a standard out of the box 3d cart sample store with sample products.  We can verify that the product with the correct catalogid has images.

The response we got is http 200 code and an empty array [].

We tried different values for limit and offset.

Could you advise?  Did we use the wrong api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article 
https://apirest.3dcart.com/Help/Api/GET-3dCartWebAPI-v1-Products-catalogid-Images_limit_offset
is wrong. Now we need use the url

```
http://apirest.3dcart.com/3dCartWebAPI/v1/Products?catalogid=XXXX
```

for images.

You would get a collection with the image information as follows:

```
"MainImageFile":"assets/images/generic/tshirt.jpg",
"MainImageCaption":"",
"ThumbnailFile":"assets/images/generic/tshirt_thumbnail.jpg",
"MediaFile":"",
"AdditionalImageFile2":"",
"AdditionalImageCaption2":"",
"AdditionalImageFile3":"",
"AdditionalImageCaption3":"",
"AdditionalImageFile4":"",
"AdditionalImageCaption4":"",
"ImageGalleryList":
```

Thanks.